# Turning a 2D plot-directory into a 3D one

Tags: python, matrix, trigonometry

I'm new to this forum, so first of all thanks for taking the time to read. I hope I have posted this in the right place!

My problem is not exactly simple, but I don;t think it's an enormous stretch to solve for someone skilled in the field. So here goes:

Problem
For a personal project I am trying to create a plot of points in 3D space with coordinates (X,Y,Z) using a combination of 2-dimensional Points.

To do this I have three or four (solution can contain either 3 or 4) directories each including points with no depth A(x,y), B(x,y), C(x,y), D(x,y).

```
Plot1 = {'A1':[x,y], 'B1':[x,y], 'C1':[x,y], 'D1':[x,y] }
Plot2 = {'A2':[x,y], 'B2':[x,y], 'C2':[x,y], 'D2':[x,y] }
Plot3 = {'A3':[x,y], 'B3':[x,y], 'C3':[x,y], 'D3':[x,y] }
Plot4 = {'A4':[x,y], 'B4':[x,y], 'C4':[x,y], 'D4':[x,y] }
```

Each of the 2D points in each plot, actually represent the same point in a 3D space. E.g. A is the same point in space in plot1 as in plot2. So the distance in 3D space between each of the points A, B, C, D is constant.

The problem is: How can I determine the (X,Y,Z) values for each of the points A, B, C and D so I get:

```
Plot3D = {'A':[x,y,z], 'B':[x,y,z], 'C':[x,y,z], 'D':[x,y,z] }
```

If it helps, one can also assume that the points represent a plane.

Thoughts:
I work in Python, but that's not really the essence here I think, but gladly take comments. I imagine that I need some sort of combination between trigonometry and matrix calculation, but have no idea where to start. Any help or direction you can give here would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to solve for solutions in 3d space that satisfy Plots[1-4]?  Could you give a simple example of points and a possible 3d solution?

Comment: It is really unclear what you're trying to do. Could you tell us more about your application or provide a mathematical formula to get from A_i(x,y) to A(x,y,z)?

Comment: DinoOcch, that's a good way to say it, The issue that the plots each represent different viewing angles of the same 2D-object (the plane) I would post an image to explain better but need 10 in reputation :(

Psirius: I have to admit this is much of a math problem. I don't have that formula, but am looking for way to get there through math/python In some sense I think what we are trying to solve this column vector:

Z = [z1,z2,z3,z4]

And we already have this matrix (with values)

XY =
|x1, y1|
|x2, y2|
|x3, y3|
|x4, y4|

Does that make more sense? I think we need trigonometry...